# Symfony3 + FOSuserBundle : database is already in sync + Authentication request could not be processed

Tags: symfony, authentication, doctrine-orm, orm, fosuserbundle

I'm learning how to use FOSuserBundle and I've finished configuring it following  the steps from the Symfony docs : [Getting Started With FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

The problem is that when I want to update the database schema (`doctrine:schema:update --force`) I get :

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

But I think that it should update the user table.

This is my User class :

```
namespace Stage\AdminBundle\Bundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

So when I try to login :"**Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.
"**   appears.

I don't know what should I do , please help me 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

finally i've found the solution , it's a mistake in the namespace 
it's :: namespace Stage\AdminBundle\Bundle\Entity;
but it should be namespace Stage\AdminBundle\Entity;